# Excel HSTACK function disappeared, whats the cause how to resolve?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

Over the past month or so I've been using the excel [HSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2) function to join columns together and create an output table.

I changed a computer, in the morning on the new computer I was using HSTACK in various function, then in the evening while I was working on it, The HSTACK function suddenly stopped working and started giving the #NAME error.

What can cause HSTACK to suddenly disappear, is there a random excel bug that could have caused it could it be something changed in the Microsoft 365 subscription, if so what would change to switch it off?

Browsing on the internet I could not find anything that explains HSTACK dissapearing.

Comment: I don't know. I have Excel 365 and HSTACK is alive and well. Try repairing Office.

Comment: May be related to a corporate environment.

Comment: Is VSTACK present? What about WRAPCOLS, WRAPROWS, TEXTSPLIT, TEXTAFTER, TEXTBEFORE, BYCOL and BYROW?

Comment: The [HSTACK function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2) may give an error "If an array has fewer rows than the maximum width of the selected arrays". Have the arguments to the function changed?